# I need a Regular Expression to validate single or multiple cities in a if statement:

Tags: javascript

I have a text box where a user enters a single value or values separated by semicolor.

Example: London;

Example: London;Paris;

Example: Toronto;Paris;New York; London;

I have an array of objects like the following:

```
    arr = [
    { name: "joe",   city: " Toronto;Paris;New York; London;"},
    { name: "nick",  city: " London;"},
    { name: "blast", city: " London;Paris;"}
];
```

I need a Regular Expression to validate single or multiple cities in a if statement: for example if a user enters “London;”  then I should get all 3 records. If a user enters “London; Paris;” then I should get the 2 records with “name” "joe" and "blast".

I have done somthing like that for other dropdown but I am not satisfied with this approach:

```
var SubSpecialtiesArray = $("#SubSpecialtiesDropDown").multiselect("getChecked").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
var GeographicalLocationArray = $("#GeographicalLocationDropDown").multiselect("getChecked").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
for (var j = 0; j < gAssessorsInfoArray.length; j++) {
    if ((gAssessorsInfoArray[j].AvailableForRegular.indexOf(gServiceInfoArray[0].ServiceName) > -1 ||
          gAssessorsInfoArray[j].AvailableForCAT.indexOf(gServiceInfoArray[0].ServiceName) > -1) &&
          ($("#YearsOfExperienceDropDown").val() == "" ||
          $("#YearsOfExperienceDropDown").val() == gAssessorsInfoArray[j].YearsOfExperience) &&
          ($("#P104DropDown").val() == "" || $("#P104DropDown").val() == gAssessorsInfoArray[j].P104)) {
        if (SubSpecialtiesArray == "" && GeographicalLocationArray == "")
            AssessorsIDSArray.push(gAssessorsInfoArray[j].UserID);
        else {
            var FoundCounter = 0;
            for (var k = 0; k < SubSpecialtiesArray.length; k++) {
                if (gAssessorsInfoArray[j].SubSpecialties.indexOf(SubSpecialtiesArray[k]) > -1)
                    FoundCounter++;
            }
            if (SubSpecialtiesArray.length == FoundCounter)
                AssessorsIDSArray.push(gAssessorsInfoArray[j].UserID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give it a shot and let us know how we can help.

Comment: You may also consider that you are matching exact strings, so a regex is likely overkill.

Comment: Easier if you change to `city: ["Toronto", "Paris", ... ]},`

Comment: Reason for re-open vote: It's very clear what the OP wants: Filter the array of objects on whether or not the object's `city` string contains a certain city.

Comment: And this is how to do that -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2eSyj/**

Comment: @adeneo: I literally just now added something quite similar to my answer xD

Answer (score 0):

For only one search item, try this:

```
arr = [
    { name: "joe",   city: " Toronto;Paris;New York; London;"},
    { name: "nick",  city: " London;"},
    { name: "blast", city: " London;Paris;"}
];

var search = "Paris;";

var result = arr.filter(function(element){
    return element.city.indexOf(search) !== -1;
});
```

Then, result equals:

```
result == [
    { name: "joe",   city: " Toronto;Paris;New York; London;"},
    { name: "blast", city: " London;Paris;"}
];
```

If you want to test for multiple cities:

Assuming:

```
var search = "Toronto;Paris;"

var searchArray = search.split(';').filter(function(element){return element.trim() !== ''});

var result = arr.filter(function(element){
    for(var i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++){
        if(element.city.indexOf(searchArray[i].trim()) !== -1;){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```